# Overlay is true but my indicator on seperated chart

Tags: pine-script

I have developed a strategy and converted it to an indicator (to easily integrate it with bots) but even though my overlay is set to true the indicator is on a separated chart and I cannot see the tp/sl lines easily on that little chart. How can I fix that?

```
    indicator("My Strategy on Study", overlay=true)
    ...
    plot(pacL, color=color.blue, linewidth=1, title="High PAC EMA", transp=0)
    plot(pacU, color=color.purple, linewidth=1, title="Low PAC EMA", transp=0)
    plot(pacC, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Close PAC EMA", transp=0)
    ...
    plotshape(longSLhit, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.gray, size=size.tiny, title="Long SL", text=" Long SL", textcolor=color.white)
    plotshape(shortSLhit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.gray, size=size.tiny, title="Short SL", text=" Short SL", textcolor=color.white)
    plotshape(longTPhit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.purple, size=size.tiny, title="Long TP", text="Long TP", textcolor=color.white)
    plotshape(shortTPhit, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.purple, size=size.tiny, title="Short TP", text="Short TP", textcolor=color.white)
    ...
    plot(long_short==1  ? longStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Fixed SL")
    plot(long_short==-1 ? shortStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Short Fixed SL")
    plot(long_short==1  ? longTake : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="Long Fixed TP")
    plot(long_short==-1 ? shortTake : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green, linewidth=1, title="Short Fixed TP")
```

[My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqmmg.png)

Comment: Could it be that when you added it to your chart overlay was set to `false` and then you changed it to `true` without removing the indicator from your chart? What I’m trying to say is, what happens when you remove the indicator from your chart and add again?

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. You are right. I removed and add again and now it's alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you started working on an indicator where `overlay=false` and added it to your chart, you should remove the indicator from your chart and add again after you set overlay to `true`.